# Why not all items append into array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have the struct in User.swift file:

```
struct User {
    let name : String
    let image: UIImage
}
```

And in my controller I do:

```
for user in OneRoster.buddyList.fetchedObjects! {
    let userJID = OneRoster.userFromRosterForJID(jid: user.jidStr)
    var avatarImage: UIImage?

    let photoData = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppvCardAvatarModule?.photoDataForJID(userJID?.jid)
    self.users = [User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!)
}
```

So I run a loop and when I print elements(user) it prints all users, but when I try to:

```
self.users = [User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!)
```

it adds to my `var users = [User]()` just the one, the last, user and ignores first ones. So, when I print `print(users)` it prints just the last user.

I cannot understand why? How can I fix it, that all users will append into my array?

Comment: `self.users = [....]` *assigns* an array to the users property, so what do you expect? You are not *appending* to the array anywhere in your code.

Comment: Because you are not appending items.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially answerable by looking at one's own code.

Comment: Btw. this cannot be your real code because there is no closing square bracket in the `self.users = [ ...` line.

Comment: This question is valid. he might got confused with the swift array syntax. he explained his problem and got a valid answer. no need to close anything

Comment: @giorashc thanks! Yes, I just confused with the syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
self.users.append(User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!)
```

Instead of

```
self.users = [User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You modify your `users` array every time inside cycle, so it get rewrite, change this line:

```
self.users = [User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!)
```

on

```
self.users.append(User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!)
```

and add initializing your array to top if you don't have it:

```
self.users = [User]()
```